# Length validation of masked Input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following masked field:

```
<input id="phone1" placeholder="(___) ___-____"/>
```

masking is done like this:

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $("#phone1").inputmask({ "mask": "(999) 999-9999" });
        </script>
```

I want to do the length validation of the phone field. The phone field should be exactly 10 characters long or with masked input, it should be 14 characters long.
I don't want to do the validation on submit button, but I want to do the length validation of phone field "onfocusout" or when someone tabs out of the field. I just want to display a message underneath the phone field saying "this field should be 10 characters long" if someone puts less than 10 character. This masking is not letting the user put more than 10 character. This phone field is not a required field.

any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define validation on `.keyup` event, so if there is any validation error, it will display when the user is typing. Use `.replace(/\D/g,'')` to remove the non-numerical string.

```js
$(".phone").inputmask({ "mask": "(999) 999-9999" }).keyup((e) => {
  if(e.target) {
    let value = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g,'');
    if (value.length < 10) {
      $(e.target).next(".error").html('this field should be 10 characters long');
    } else {
      $(e.target).next(".error").html('');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>

<input id="phone1" class="phone" placeholder="(___) ___-____"/>
<div class="error"></div>
<input id="phone2" class="phone" placeholder="(___) ___-____"/>
<div class="error"></div>
<input id="phone3" class="phone" placeholder="(___) ___-____"/>
<div class="error"></div>
```

Comment: this works like a charm. I have several phone fields like cell phone, home phone, work phone. Can you modify the above script to accommodate all the phone fields or is it not possible and I have to write the same JavaScript for each phone field.

Comment: @rimi,, you can add the same class name to all the input  like
`<input class="phone-mask" name="phone">
<input class="phone-mask" name="cell_phone">`
And use it like 

`$(".phone-mask").inputmask({ "mask": "(999) 999-9999" }).keyup((e) => {`

Comment: @Jordy  why to use `let id = e.target.id.split('phone')[1]; ` ? ?  when you have class

you can simply use `$(e.target).next(".error").html('this field should be 10 characters long');`

Comment: @Jordy, Although the error is displayed. I can still submit the form if I don't type all the 10 numbers in the phone field. Is their any way to prevent the submission of the form if all 10 characters of the phone fields are not typed. Phone is not required field, but if the user starts typing and does not type the entire 10 numbers then submission should be prevented.